# concentric cylinders in geometric nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

In Geometric Nodes, I wanted to build concentic cylinders that never stop growing, over 1,800 images.
I succeeded, but the setup is very cumbersome.
For each cylinder, you need about ten nodes.
For the final fifty cylinders, you end up with a toal of more than 500 nodes.
I'm sure there are ways of simplifying this, but I can't manage it.
Can a geometric nodes specialist help me?
Thank you.
https://youtu.be/xej2wZ3sVeQ
[image][image]

Answer (score 5):

Using a simulation zone (Blender 4.0) for animation:

[image]

[image]

Create a cylinder.

Orient it.

Go into simulation zone.

Scale instance, and add another one when some frame is reached (modulo something from the frame).

Then after the simulation zone, extrude the cylinder(s).

Comment: A sim zone was added in B3.6

Comment: Tank you so much for your help. I'll try asap.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, using repeat zone, introduced in 4.0, you can do it much simpler way:

[image]

Also, try to avoid using Mesh Boolean. It is very slow!

Input value in repeat zone animated:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But is this a growing scale like in the video? I'm not on a computer right now to check, but this looks very static to me.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I didn't know that answers without GIF is not acceptable in this topic.

Comment: Never said it's not acceptable. It was not about the static image, I was asking if that would move because your setup before editing the answer had no keyframed value or used a _Scene Time_ node like in the question.

Comment: Thanks very much. Back to work!

Answer (score 1):

No need for a simulation zone:

- Ensure the scales of `count` cylinders divide the maximum radius (scale of 1): `max`, exactly
- Scale duplicates `(index*(max/count) + (speed*scene time)) mod (max)`

[image]

For this effect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: well... this is not the same effect, but why not... +1

Comment: Have a look to the youtube video linked in the question

Comment: @lemon I did.. the only difference I see is a sort of Boolean fudge near zero. Else, arithmetic progression in scale, OK, matched .. the relative thickness, height,  (easily set by curve profile, here) camera angle.. we'll see .. I'm too late anyway.. except for your kind UV  :)